# Starting gitk Error

Tags: git, macos, gitk

When I'm loading gitk I get an error about an argument

```
Error in startup script: bad argument "zoomed": must be normal, iconic, or withdrawn
    while executing
"wm state . $geometry(state)"
    (procedure "makewindow" line 320)
    invoked from within
"makewindow"
    (file "/usr/local/git/bin/gitk" line 11250)
```

Anybody knows a solution? I'm working on Mac OS X 10.6.3

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mention in this [blog post](http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Ftechlifejourney.blogspot.com%2F):

使用Macport安裝mercurial結果安裝了一堆相依的library，結果造成gitk不能執行

Err... I meant:

> The results using Macport installation, mercurial installs a bunch of dependencies of the library, resulting in a gitk which can not perform.
>
> Gitk will use the wrong tk library version.

The issue was that the first installation has modified the `.bashrc` with:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

modifying the original PATH (`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`)

Try instead in the `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

Comment: thx, that was the issue.

I've found this article to, but I can't read japanese (or chinese...???) :-D

big thx!

Comment: @23tux: err... just so we are clear: I can't read Chinese (it is Chinese) either. Hence the translate.google link ;)

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem on Lion. This was my solution:

```
cd 
rm -rf .gitk
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. In what directory do you change? And is .gitk a file or a dir? Please provide more information (btw, I solved it already)

Comment: with the command cd (without any argument) you go to your home directory.

Comment: The file .gitk is a configuration file for gitk (It contains a lot of parameters including the ones for the geometry settings). If you delete it, gitk will regenerate this file (with the right settings). That's why this solution worked for me! I know you already solved this problem, but in my case I did not have any .bashrc file in my home directory. So, your solution was not applicable.

Answer (score 4):

Look for the ~/.gitk startup script in your home directory.  It will probably contain a line like `set geometry(state) normal`.  Make sure the ~/.gitk file has Unix-style line endings rather than DOS line endings, i.e. LF not LFCR.

You may be able to fix things up by deleting ~/.gitk and allowing it to be recreated when you next run gitk, as noted by ejfresch. 
~~~

Comment: This fixed the problem, it was "zoomed" instead of "normal" by changing it to normal the issue stopped immediately!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently on Ubuntu 18.04.

I deleted .config/git/gitk in the home directory and everything was fine again.