# where is $PATH set? Specifically where is my mac port path being set?

Tags: linux, macos, path, macports

when i do

```
 echo $PATH
```

is see:

```
  /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

I want to move the /opt/local stuff to the end of the path because it is causing errors with gitk.  (the same error specified here: [Starting gitk Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629292/starting-gitk-error))

I've already commented out the export PATH line in my .bash_profile, but my path is STILL set like the above.  I also checked etc/paths.d  but don't see anything for mac ports in there.  I commented out a similar export PATH line in my .profile.  Again my path is STILL containing /opt/local in the front.  WHERE ELSE is this being set?

I'm using mac os snow leopard 10.6.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my system, MacPorts installer put it into `/etc/profile`.

The (full?) list of files is as follows (in the order `bash` reads them):

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
```

Comment: how you can open it to edit with an editor?

Answer (score 4):

Did you also check /etc/profile or /etc/paths? It seems to me if you commented it out from all the other places, those would be the places where they would be.